# Editing a referenced class

Tags: java, oop, maven, inheritance

I'm working with a Maven project. In a referenced JAR there is a package, which contains a class file. I need to add some lines of code to this class, but unfortunately this class it not editable.
My idea was to create a new class, extend it from this referenced class and add my lines of code to the newly created class. The problem here is, the code is a bit complex and the classes extend from one another.

```
// existing class
public class ReferencedClass extends AnotherClass{
  // ...
}
// my idea
public class MyClass extends ReferencedClass{
  // add my code here
}

// where those classes are needed
public class SomeClass{
  anObject o = new anObject(); // creates new object, whose class also extends from ReferencedClass
}
// this class also extends from ReferencedClass
public class anObject extends ReferencedClass{
  // ...
}
```

I'm not sure, how to instantiate my own created class `MyClass`. Should I do it in all classes, where `ReferencedClass` is also used?
Is there another solution to my problem, without creating a new class at all?

Thank you!

Comment: If I were you, I'd make a wrapper class, and use only that class in your own project/code.

Comment: It's difficult to provide meaningful advice, but if the class you want to modify isn't yours, you probably shouldn't modify it. Whether or not you should extend the same class is difficult to say without knowing what you really want to do with it. Alternatives include things like AOP, simple composition with delegation, decorators, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I only need to add a short setter-method.

Comment: @stealthjong: You mean a wrapper around the referenced class? Could you provide me with a short example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify a field without a setter, a wrapper isn't useful. Whether or not the next solution is useful, is dependant on whether or not the field you are trying to modify is `private` or `protected`. If the access modifier is private, only instances of the class itself can modify the field. If protected, a child class can also access and modify the field.

```
//this is our class within the library. We cant edit its source
class APIClass {
    private int privatefield;
    protected int protectedfield;

    public String doStuff() { ... }
    public int doMoreStuff() { ... }
}

class MyExtendedAPIClass extends APIClass {
    // you dont have to override doStuff and doMoreStuff

    void setValues() {
        protectedfield = 10; //compiles, protectedfield is protected
        privatefield = 1; //does not compile, privatefield is private
    }
}
```

If it's a `private` field, and you still want to change its value, you can use reflection (in that case, you don't need another class):

```
void setFieldWithReflection() {
    APIClass apiClass = new APIClass();
    try {
        Field fieldToEdit = apiClass.getClass().getField("privatefield");
        fieldToEdit.set(apiClass, 25);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Edit: Since a setter merely sets a field, you can just set that field using reflection. But OP demands it to be a method (which I don't get, but OK), I'd go with this implementation:

```
//this is our class within the library. We cant edit its source
class APIClass {
    private int privatefield;

    public int getPrivatefield() {
        return privatefield;
    }
}

class MyExtendedAPIClass extends APIClass {
    // you dont have to override doStuff and doMoreStuff

    public void setPrivatefield(int value) {
        try {
            Field field = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("privatefield");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(this, value);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Above works. Test with code

```
MyExtendedAPIClass mApi = new MyExtendedAPIClass();
mApi.setPrivatefield(5);
System.out.println(mApi.getPrivatefield);//outputs '5'
```

Comment: Thank you! I just need to add another setter method to the class, without modifying any fields.